# Xamarin.iOS Unhandled Error launching soft debugger:System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, ios, debugging, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I am using Xamarin.iOS to make a universal iOS app. I can build using the iOS Simulator but when I use the Live Player to preview the app I get the following errors.

[image]

[image]

```
Got device info: James’s iPhone Player (iOS) @ 192.168.1.90:37847
Synchronizing files...
Building and running...
Built with 0 messages.
Deploy to James’s iPhone Player succeeded.
Could not connect to the debugger.
```

If I use 'Start without debugging' the Simulator in works just the same but when I do it with the Live player it deploys correctly but then just stays black.

I am using the following versions:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.5.6
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.5.6+27130.2027
Installed Version: Community
Xamarin   4.8.0.760 (fc93f3f5b)
Xamarin Designer   4.8.188 (c5813fa34)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   11.6.1.4 (db807ec)
```

Comment: Do you want to add this as an answer and I will select it and close :)

Comment: Alright, I'll add it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin Live Player can't work on iOS now: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95825/ios-run-time-errors-type-or-namespace-name-not-found-with-xamarin-live-player-and-hanselman-forms. As JamesMontemagno said, you can try Test Flight Fast Ring version.

Comment: Installed the TestFlight beta and it works just fine now. Thank you